# Thanos: unmarshal errors:\n line 2: field encryptsse not found in type s3.Config

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, thanos, kube-prometheus-stack

I have the same error when I helm install the latest version prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack with thanos.io v0.25.2 the thanos-storage-config.yaml as following:

```
type: s3
config:
  bucket: monitoring-thanos-dev-metrics #S3 bucket name
  endpoint: s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com #S3 Regional endpoint
  encryptsse: true
```

Then, the thanos-sidecar, thanos-compactor and thanos-sotre has show this error msg: unmarshal errors:\n line 2: field encryptsse not found in type s3.Config

Comment: the both thanos pod: thanos-compactor and thanos-store has the same error log: unmarshal errors:\n  line 2: field encryptsse not found in type s3.Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation:](https://thanos.io/v0.8/thanos/storage.md/#s3)

```yaml
type: S3
config:
  bucket: ""
  endpoint: ""
  region: ""
  access_key: ""
  insecure: false
  signature_version2: false
  encrypt_sse: false
  secret_key: ""
  put_user_metadata: {}
  http_config:
    idle_conn_timeout: 0s
    response_header_timeout: 0s
    insecure_skip_verify: false
  trace:
    enable: false
  part_size: 0
```

it seems you have a type in the key name: **encrypt_sse**

I had similar errors, to workaround I just removed the *encrypt_sse: false* key.

> At a minimum, you will need to provide a value for the bucket, endpoint, access_key, and secret_key keys. The rest of the keys are optional.